# Multiple SELECT queries at the same time

Tags: sqlite, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

Using react-native-sqlite-storage library

There is data loading in two tabs. In the first tab, we are loading a large amount of entities from the database (SELECT query), and that takes about 1 minute. During that 1 minute, if you navigate to the other tab, data is also loaded from the database (SELECT query). The second query will start when the first is finished. In sqlite, it should be possible to have multiple selects at the same time. Any help is welcome

Here is the code to fetch the data from the db:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   db.executeSql(sqlStatement, [], (results) => {
      resolve(results.rows.raw());
   })
});
```

Comment: *we are loading a large amount of entities into the database (SELECT query)* Do you mean INSERT?

Comment: No, i mean SELECT

Comment: So what is the question?  There is a statement about "it should be possible", but no mention of behavior or errors for the code.  Is the question about proper configuration of sqlite?